# Create own beacons service for Proximity based mobile application

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

We are developed Beacon proximity based mobile application using third party Beacon SDK(Android |iOS).Now we want to create own beacon service & management.As my understanding Android/iOS have api for supporting BLE devices.Can anyone help me how can i start from scratch(Write beacon api | Where i can buy beacon).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't say exactly what you want tour Beacon SDK to do (detect beacons?  configure beacons?  manage beacons in the cloud?)

If you want to learn how a detection SDK works, a good place to look is the open source [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), which implements similar features as provided by the iOS `CoreLocation` beacon APIs.  The full source code is available [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library).

As the lead developer on this project, I caution that implementing basic beacon detection functionality is simple, but more advanced features (background detection that is battery friendly, beacon transmission, supporting a wide variety of devices) gets complex quickly.   Be careful that you don't bite off too much and re-invent the wheel.

Shameless plug:  Since you asked where to buy beacons, Radius Networks offers a full line of both [battery and A/C powered beacons](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/collections/all).

Full disclosure:  I am Chief Engineer at Radius Networks.

Comment: Thanks David.Want to Configure and manage beacon.So Any  library will have to get full control for my application?

Comment: You should note that for configuring beacons, there is no standard -- every vendor uses their own mechanism.  Often it is done through a proprietary bluetooth GATT interface, sometimes through a proprietary USB serial port interface.  Often these interfaces are not documented, so it may not be possible (and it certainly will be difficult) to make a SDK that supports universal configuration across all beacon manufacturers.